# How to merge rows by grouping and only keep highest value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

Suppose the following data frame:

```
dfX <- data.frame('a' = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'),
              'b' = c('c2', 'c2', 'c8', 'c8', 'c4', 'c7', 'c7', 'c9', 'c9','c9'),
              'c' = c('f34', 'f34', 'm92', 'm92', 'm92', 'g22', 'g22', 'i41', 'i41', 'i41'),
              'd' = c('Check', 'Check', 'Check', 'Check', 'UnCheck', 'Check', 'Check', 'Check', 'Check','Check'),
              'val1' = c(54, '', 37, '', '', 51, '', 74, '', ''),
              'val2' = c('', 59, '', 87, 84, '', 62, '', 27, 85))

dfX
    a   b   c    d       val1  val2
1   A1  c2  f34  Check   54 
2   A1  c2  f34  Check         59
3   A2  c8  m92  Check   37 
4   A2  c8  m92  Check         87
5   A2  c4  m92  UnCheck       84
6   A3  c7  g22  Check   51 
7   A3  c7  g22  Check         62
8   A4  c9  i41  Check   74 
9   A4  c9  i41  Check         27
10  A4  c9  i41  Check         85
```

I would like to merge columns `val1` and `val2` grouping them by the equivalent values of columns `a, b, c`, BUT if column `d` says `'Uncheck'`, then the row should be erased from the resulting data frame.
On top of that, if there is more than one value in a column per group (like in case of rows `A4`), only the highest value of the repeated column should be kept

So far I was aiming with `dplyr` something like this:  ([This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780465/collapse-data-frame/30780856#30780856) as source)

```
FuncX <- function(x) x[x != '']

dfY <- dfX %>%
  group_by(a,b,c) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(FuncX))
```

But adding the `d` column and the said condition that if this column marks `'Unchecked'`, then it should be erased, I couldn't find a way around it. Also failed at having as output only the `max()` value of the `A4` rows

The desired output should be like so:

```
dfY
    a   b   c    d       val1  val2
1   A   c2  f34  Check   54    59
2   B   c8  m92  Check   37    87
3   C   c7  g22  Check   51    62
4   D   c9  i41  Check   74    85
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to convert to numeric to get the `max`.  The 'val1', 'val2' are `character` class (NOTE: We are using `R 4.0.0` where `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` by default in `data.frame` construct.  If the R version is < 4.0, then it would be `stringsAFactors = TRUE` by default and then the `as.numeric(.)` in the below should be changed to `as.numeric(as.character(.))`)

```
library(dplyr)
dfX %>%
    filter(d == 'Check') %>% 
    group_by(a, b, c, d) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with('val')), ~ max(as.numeric(.), na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   a, b, c [4]
#  a     b     c     d      val1  val2
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A     c2    f34   Check    54    59
#2 B     c8    m92   Check    37    87
#3 C     c7    g22   Check    51    62
#4 D     c9    i41   Check    74    85
```

---

Or with `summarise/across` in the new version of `dplyr`

```
dfX %>%
 filter(d == 'Check') %>% 
 group_by(a, b, c, d) %>% 
 summarise(across(starts_with('val'), ~ max(as.numeric(.), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `aggregate`

```
dfX[c('val1', 'val2')] <- lapply(dfX[c('val1', 'val2')], as.numeric)
aggregate(. ~ a + b + c+ d, dfX,subset = d == 'Check', max,
      na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```

Or as @Onyambu suggested, the `.` can also be on the rhs of `~` to select the rest of the columns as grouping columns

```
aggregate(cbind(val1, val2) ~ ., dfX,subset = d == 'Check', max,
      na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```

Comment: quick answer. You could also do `aggregate(cbind(val1.val2)~........)`

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, your data.frame has val1 and val2 as factors, we can do this:

```
dfX %>% 
mutate_at(c("val1","val2"),~replace(as.character(.x),.x=="",NA)) %>% 
filter(d=="Check") %>% 
group_by(a,b,c,d) %>% 
summarize_all(~max(as.numeric(.x),na.rm=TRUE))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   a, b, c [4]
  a     b     c     d     val1  val2 
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr> <chr>
1 A     c2    f34   Check 54    59   
2 B     c8    m92   Check 37    87   
3 C     c7    g22   Check 51    62   
4 D     c9    i41   Check 74    85
```